# Inverting javafx.scene.control.Slider

Tags: java, javafx

I need to invert a Slider in javafx.

This is how I built the slider:

```
Slider slide = new Slider();
slide.setPrefHeight(height);
slide.setMin(0);
slide.setMax(100);
slide.setOrientation(javafx.geometry.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
slide.setShowTickLabels(true);
slide.setShowTickMarks(true);
slide.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

This code creates a horizontally aligned slider from value 0 to 100.
But I would like to invert it. As in, place it horizontally but display values from 100 to 0. and not 0 to 100.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to invert the slider, without actually doing it, is by using a custom label formatter. Then you just need to take the value and revert it too.

Something like this:

```
private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "#,##0.00" );
private final double MIN = 0d;
private final double MAX = 100d;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox vbox=new VBox(20);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));

    Slider slide = new Slider();
    slide.setPrefSize(300,100);
    slide.setMin(MIN);
    slide.setMax(MAX);
    slide.setOrientation(javafx.geometry.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    slide.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slide.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slide.setSnapToTicks(true);
    slide.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>(){

        @Override
        public String toString(Double object) {
            return df.format(MAX-object+MIN);
        }

        @Override
        public Double fromString(String string) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }

    });

    Label label = new Label("Value: ");
    slide.valueProperty().addListener((ov,n,n1)->
          label.setText("Value: "+(MAX-n1.doubleValue()+MIN)));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(slide, label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Is there no shorter method to do this? I don't wish to create an anonymous inner class.

Comment: This approach (use a regular `Slider` control and modify its aspect) requires a function for formatting the label for the ticks, otherwise it will use the default function defined in its skin. How do you pass this function is up to you (inner anonymous class is the usual way in this case), but you can create a class just for this custom formatter, and pass and instance of this class. The result will be the same, but with more code... Other approach will be creating a new custom control, by modifying the `Slider` control to invert the slider. I'm not sure you want to go there...

Comment: It will be easier to make reversed scale from -MAX to -MIN. So in LabelFormatter you will only need to remove minus sign.